# What to do when you don't get answers from Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, community

I have question [#190306](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/190306) for more than 10 days without an answer. Usually, I get answers from the Ubuntu experts within a couple of days. The problem that I have is persistent and annoying. Where should I go?

Comment: Well, you can also ask the experts here.

Comment: ask your question here too

Answer (score 2):

Ask the same question here on AskUbuntu. I don't mean to denigrate the efforts or expertise of the Launchpad Answers folks—and for extremely technical, project code-related questions they may be the best to ask—but the community here is more vibrant and less fractured, and the software more attuned to preventing good questions from falling down the cracks.

Follow the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), and you're nearly certain to get some sort of resolution here.

Comment: Thanks. I will copy paste my question here. It's rather long and technical, but appreciate the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) to provide the best answers for questions like the one you posted at launchpad. Ask Ubuntu is good for very specific questions but the forums are more suited to solving open problems.

Comment: May I ask whoever downvoted this answet: why -1?

Comment: I posted the same question at Ubuntu forums, and unfortunately, haven't received any answer from the , yet.